# Qt 5.12 QTest library output not shown in Windows output in Azure pipeline

Tags: windows, azure-devops, qt5, qtest

I'm using Azure pipelines to build and test an application in both Linux and Windows.
The QTest output us shown perfectly fine in Linux, but information about failed tests are not listed in Windows.

Under Linux, the below is shown when executing the test (forcing a failure using QVERIFY(false))
`********* Start testing of SslConfigAwareTest ********* Config: Using QtTest library 5.12.2, Qt 5.12.2 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 6.2.0) QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString:      OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 PASS   : SslConfigTest::initTestCase() FAIL!  : SslConfigTest::generateCertificateSigningRequestTest() 'false' returned FALSE. () Loc: [/unittests/utils/sslconfig.cpp(230)] PASS   : SslConfigTest::cleanupTestCase() ********* Finished testing of SslConfigAwareTest ********* Terminating SslConfigTest - rc: 2`

But, under Windows, all I get is
`QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString:      OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019 Terminating SslConfigTest - rc: 2`

None of the config or Start/Finished messages show up, neither the very important FAIL! output with reason, file and line references while my own "QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString" and "Terminating SslConfigTest" ouput is printed.

The expectation is to see the QTest output also under Windows.